# Opencv installation problem

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I tried to install opencv using cmake to work with gpu. After installation, I try to confirm installation. So, I open anaconda prompt and python >> then import cv2. However, I got the error of module not found.
I couldn't find a solution for that on the Internet. Does anyone know how I can solve it?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV? Which version is installed? Did you use pip or pip3?

Comment: @Mateus Oliveira Cabral I installed opencv from source  using cmake and visual studio. During configuration, it does not seem that I get any error. But in anaconda when I call python and then import cv2 I get no module found. Opencv version is 4.4.0